# Jenkins2 Pipeline: deploy on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm a newbie on Jenkins Pipelines. I wrote this small Groovy script from pulling from git and compiling.

```
node('master') {
  def workspace = pwd()

  stage 'Git pull'
  git branch: 'develop', 
  credentialsId: 'Cred_xxxx', 
  url: 'https://xxxx/yyyy.git'

  stage 'Builing'
  def mvnHome = tool name: 'Maven3', type: 'hudson.tasks.Maven$MavenInstallation'
  sh "cd ${workspace}/tlt/; ${mvnHome}/bin/mvn install -Pdevelopment"
  sh "cd ${workspace}"
}
```

Now I would like to deploy on Tomcat7 the file `tlt/target/tlt.war`. 
The previous approach was to fill the "Deploy war/ear to container" plugin. 
Now, I have no idea how to do this with Groovy.

Thanks
Riccardo

Answer (score 7):

When using Jenkinsfile you need to copy the war yourself to the tomcat using groovy script.

If Tomcat is on the same server you can do just:

```
sh 'cp tlt/target/tlt.war TOMCAT_DIRECTORY/webapps/'
```

If on other host you would need to do `scp` and configure user and password:

```
sshagent(['CREDENTIALS_ID']) {
    sh 'scp tlt/target/tlt.war some-remote-host:/LOCATION/TOMCAT/webapps/'
}
```

where `CREDENTIALS_ID` is the ID take from the URL of credentials that you need to add in jenkins credentials page (it is in the url, a string like 4644a37d-4291-474e-813b-14b58bef1125).

Comment: @Riccardo79 It depends where your tomcat is located, is it on the same host?

Comment: Thanks.. And how to reload the war? Is it necessari?

Comment: It is worse than using "Deploy war/ear to container" because you don't know the deployment result, whether app started in tomcat or not.

Comment: This solution implies SSH is active and running on the target server, which is a pretty tough assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, more easy is to create a Job with only the task "Deploy war/ear to container" and to call it through the "build" command in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to put the user, like this:

```
sshagent(['CREDENTIALS_ID']) {
    sh 'scp tlt/target/tlt.war root@some-remote-host:/LOCATION/TOMCAT/webapps/'
}
```

Without user the task block in this step